# Display misconception in django-tables2

Tags: django, django-models, accessor, django-tables2

After creating a custom user model in my app, I have a studentProfile that inherits from the user model, which also contains avatar, semester, and dept_name. which works fine. However, when I was trying to display this studentProfile data using django-tables2, all rows keeps showing "-" and the ID been captured is from user model instead of studentProfile.

> The weirdiest thing is i can get all the values from user model
>   correctly even when studentProfile is my table model for
>   django-tables2

I don't know what I am doing wrongly. Any help is really appreciated

my model definitions are as follow

```
class DepartmentData(models.Model):
    fid = models.ForeignKey(FacultyData, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dept_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dept_name



class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    # add additional fields here
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)# can login
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # staff user non superuser
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # superuser

    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'student'),
        (2, 'lecturer'),
        (3, 'bursary'),
        (4, 'system'),
        (5, 'admin'),
    )

    user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'user_id'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'user_type']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_id

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

    def get_user_type(self):
            return self.user_type

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True


    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin
    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active


class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    semester = models.ForeignKey(SemesterData, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    dept_name = models.ForeignKey(DepartmentData, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name

class SemesterData(models.Model):
    sid = models.ForeignKey(SessionData, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    semester_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.semester_name

    def current(self):

        if SettingsData.objects.all().count():
            st = SettingsData.objects.get(id=1)
            if self.id == st.current_id:
                return "Current Session-Semester"
            else:
                return format_html('<a href="{}"  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">{}</a>', reverse('system:current_session_semester', args=[self.id]),
                                   'Set Current')
        else:
                return format_html('<a href="{}" class="btn btn-primary">{}</a>', reverse('system:current_session_semester', args=[self.id]),
                                   'Set Current')
```

here is my table.py

```
class StudentTable(tables.Table):

    user_id = tables.Column(attrs = {'th': {'class': 'danger'}})
    first_name = tables.Column(attrs = {'th': {'class': 'danger'}})
    last_name = tables.Column(attrs = {'th': {'class': 'danger'}})

    avatar = tables.Column(accessor ="user", verbose_name = "ass" )



    active = tables.Column(attrs = {'th': {'class': 'danger'}})

    last_login = tables.Column(attrs = {'th': {'class': 'danger'}})
    edit_Action = tables.LinkColumn('system:semester_edit', text='Edit', args=[A('pk')],attrs={'a':{'class':'btn btn-info btn-sm'}, 'td':{'align': 'center'}, 'th': {'class': 'danger'}}, orderable=False)

    class Meta:
        model = StudentProfile
        attrs = {'class':'table table-hover table-bordered table-responsive'}
        sequence = ('user_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'avatar')
        exclude = {'id', 'user', 'password', 'staff', 'admin'}
        empty_text = _("There are no students yet")
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap4.html'
```

I would love to get the department_name, semester_name as well as fields in the studentProfile which is serving as my table model

Comment: Can we see your models definitions?

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing empty values for all fields with your current configuration because you're trying to access fields `user_id`, `first_name` and `last_name` which are not fields of the `StudentProfile` model, but rather fields of the `User` model (to which `StudentProfile` is related by `user` field).

That being said, you should access those fields via the `user` relation, something like this:

```
class StudentTable(tables.Table):
    user_id = tables.Column(accessor='user.user_id', ...)
    first_name = tables.Column(accessor='user.first_name', ...)
    last_name = tables.Column(accessor='user.last_name', ...)
    ...
```

As far as the `DepartmentData` and `SemesterData` relations go, I'm not sure why aren't they displayed by default, since they are fields of the `StudentProfile` model, and they aren't excluded via the `exclude` property on the `Meta`. You can maybe try to explicitly list them in the `fields` property and see if that helps.

Comment: with this, all the values with accessor are not showing and also, avatar is a field in studentProfile that's also showing "-" as well

Comment: Moreso, i was able to get the values for the User model with what i had before, the problem is, my table is not seeing studentProfile field values as well as the related models

Comment: I set up a test project with your code and added the changes I laid out in this answer and everything works as expected, see screenshot here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pqyehgj1j2okfap/table.png?dl=0

Comment: Also, what version of `django-tables2` are you using?

Comment: i am using django 2.1.4 and django-tables2 2.0.4

Comment: I just ran into more or less the same problem, however, I don't have a custom User model but use the default one. What is strange this time though is that I have two tables using the same logic to display a username and in one table it works but not the other one. Looking at the record in the admin page shows that indeed there is a username for the corresponding records. Any suggestions how to tackle this after having tried the above solution?